# How to resolve Plugin Container Exception in building maven project with sonar:sonar?

Tags: java, maven, plugins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

After adding the custom plugins jar in extension folder of sonarqube 7.4, I am trying to build a sample project with clean package sonar:sonar. But everytime it is giving this PluginContainerException. The error is shared below:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal
org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.5.0.1254:sonar
(default-cli) on project testsonar: Execution default-cli of goal
org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.5.0.1254:sonar
failed: A required class was missing while executing
org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.5.0.1254:sonar:
org/sonar/java/model/PackageUtils [ERROR]
----------------------------------------------------- 
[ERROR] realm = plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:3.5.0.1254 [ERROR]
strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] =
file:/C:/Users/chakrabok/.m2/repository/org/sonarsource/scanner/maven/sonar-maven-plugin/3.5.0.1254/sonar-maven-plugin-3.5.0.1254.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] =
file:/C:/Users/chakrabok/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.4/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] =
file:/C:/Users/chakrabok/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] =
file:/C:/Users/chakrabok/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.22/plexus-utils-3.0.22.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] =
file:/C:/Users/chakrabok/.m2/repository/org/sonarsource/scanner/api/sonar-scanner-api/2.10.0.1189/sonar-scanner-api-2.10.0.1189.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] =
file:/C:/Users/chakrabok/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1 [ERROR] import: Entry[import 
from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]] [ERROR]  [ERROR]
-----------------------------------------------------:org.sonar.java.model.PackageUtils
```

Please tell me what to do?

Comment: Improved formatting

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this issue by using any of the following solutions:

1. Deactivate "Security Annotation Mandatory" rule in [Sonarqube web console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnC3a.png).
2. Add the following dependency in pom.xml of the project:

   `<dependencies>
      ...
      <dependency>
       <groupId>org.sonarsource.java</groupId>
       <artifactId>java-squid</artifactId>
       <version>3.11</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>`

   Make sure after adding the dependency in pom.xml, you have compiled the project (*mvn clean install*), and then copy the jar file into `<sonarqube_dir>`/*extensions/plugins/* directory and finally restart the sonarqube server.

P.S. org.sonar.java.model.PackageUtils class is imported by the [SecurityAnnotationMandatoryRule](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-custom-rules-examples/blob/master/java-custom-rules/src/main/java/org/sonar/samples/java/checks/SecurityAnnotationMandatoryRule.java) and its dependency need to be added in pom.xml.